# Probable jar conflict/missing causes BeanCreationException in Fosstrak

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, dependencies

I have imported a Java project (Fosstrak fc-server 1.2.0) in eclipse kepler for Java EE developers using Maven. It is a web project that I deployed in Tomcat7 using JRE 7. My notebook is a Macbook Pro running MacOSX 10.7.5. The project uses Spring 3.0.7
I get an exception during Tomcat startup. The exception trace is the following:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aleApplicationContext' defined in file [/Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/fc-server/WEB-INF/classes/org/fosstrak/ale/server/ALEApplicationContext.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: caught exception during setup of the critical components.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: caught exception during setup of the critical components.
    at org.fosstrak.ale.server.ALEApplicationContext.initializeApplication(ALEApplicationContext.java:84)
    at org.fosstrak.ale.server.ALEApplicationContext.setServletContext(ALEApplicationContext.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ServletContextAwareProcessor.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1505)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'logicalReaderManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.fosstrak.ale.server.ALE org.fosstrak.ale.server.readers.impl.LogicalReaderManagerImpl.ale; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ale': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.fosstrak.ale.server.impl.ALEImpl.setAleSettings(org.fosstrak.ale.server.ALESettings); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aleSettings': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String org.fosstrak.ale.server.ALESettings.vendorVersion; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'project.version' in string value "${project.version}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:272)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1125)
    at org.fosstrak.ale.server.ALEApplicationContext.getBean(ALEApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.fosstrak.ale.server.ALEApplicationContext.initializeApplication(ALEApplicationContext.java:75)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.fosstrak.ale.server.ALE org.fosstrak.ale.server.readers.impl.LogicalReaderManagerImpl.ale; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ale': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.fosstrak.ale.server.impl.ALEImpl.setAleSettings(org.fosstrak.ale.server.ALESettings); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aleSettings': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String org.fosstrak.ale.server.ALESettings.vendorVersion; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'project.version' in string value "${project.version}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ale': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.fosstrak.ale.server.impl.ALEImpl.setAleSettings(org.fosstrak.ale.server.ALESettings); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aleSettings': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String org.fosstrak.ale.server.ALESettings.vendorVersion; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'project.version' in string value "${project.version}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:912)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.fosstrak.ale.server.impl.ALEImpl.setAleSettings(org.fosstrak.ale.server.ALESettings); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aleSettings': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String org.fosstrak.ale.server.ALESettings.vendorVersion; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'project.version' in string value "${project.version}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:604)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aleSettings': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String org.fosstrak.ale.server.ALESettings.vendorVersion; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'project.version' in string value "${project.version}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:912)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String org.fosstrak.ale.server.ALESettings.vendorVersion; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'project.version' in string value "${project.version}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'project.version' in string value "${project.version}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:173)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:161)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:125)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer$PlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver.resolveStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:255)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:767)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:780)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
    ... 65 more
```

I think the issue is related to some missing dependencies or jar conflicts (because other guys can successfully run the project). This is the list of the included libraries:

```
activation-1.1.jar
comm-2.0.3.jar
jaxb-api-2.0.jar
jsr173_api-1.0.jar
mail-1.4.jar
servlet-api-2.5.jar
ant-1.7.0.jar
ant-launcher-1.7.0.jar
ant-optional-1.5.1.jar
antlr-2.7.6.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
asm-3.3.1.jar
axiom-api-1.2.7.jar
axiom-dom-1.2.7.jar
axiom-impl-1.2.7.jar
axis2-jws-api-1.4.1.jar
castor-0.9.9.1.jar
cglib-nodep-2.2.2.jar
cloning-1.8.2.jar
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
commons-beanutils-core-1.7.0.jar
commons-codec-1.3.jar
commons-collections-3.2.jar
commons-configuration-1.4.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar
commons-io-1.4.jar
commons-jxpath-1.2.jar
commons-lang-2.3.jar
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
commons-logging-api-1.0.4.jar
cxf-api-2.6.1.jar
cxf-rt-bindings-soap-2.6.1.jar
cxf-rt-bindings-xml-2.6.1.jar
cxf-rt-core-2.6.1.jar
cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-2.6.1.jar
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.6.1.jar
cxf-rt-frontend-simple-2.6.1.jar
cxf-rt-transports-http-2.6.1.jar
cxf-rt-ws-addr-2.6.1.jar
cxf-rt-ws-policy-2.6.1.jar
derby-10.4.1.3.jar
easymock-3.1.jar
geronimo-activation_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar
geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.7.1.jar
geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar
hal-commons-0.5.0.jar
hal-impl-feig-0.5.0.jar
hal-impl-impinj-0.5.0.jar
hal-impl-sim-0.5.0.jar
jaxb-impl-2.0.1.jar
jaxb-xjc-2.2.5.jar
jaxen-1.1.1.jar
jdom-1.0.jar
junit-4.8.1.jar
llrp-adaptor-1.2.1.jar
log4j-1.2.12.jar
ltkjava-1.0.0.7.jar
ltkjava-generator-1.0.0.7.jar
mina-core-1.1.7.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar
neethi-3.0.2.jar
objenesis-1.2.jar
postgresql-8.3-603.jdbc4.jar
reader-rp-proxy-0.5.0.jar
reader-rprm-core-0.5.0.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.0.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.0.jar
snmp4j-1.7.6.jar
snmp4j-agent-1.0.1.jar
spring-aop-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
stax2-api-3.1.1.jar
tdt-1.0.0.jar
woodstox-core-asl-4.1.2.jar
wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar
wstx-asl-3.2.4.jar
xalan-2.7.0.jar
xerces-1.2.3.jar
xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar
xml-apis-1.3.04.jar
xml-resolver-1.2.jarxmlschema-core-2.0.2.jar
```

Can you help me figure out the problem?
Thanks!
Roberto

**UPDATE:**
This is my applicationContext.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
  xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:ale.properties"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.fosstrak.ale" />

    <jaxws:endpoint id="ALEService"
       implementor="org.fosstrak.ale.wsdl.ale.epcglobal.ALEServicePortTypeImpl"
       endpointName="e:ALEServicePortType"
       serviceName="s:ALEService"
       address="/ALEService"
       xmlns:e="http://service.jaxws.cxf.apache.org/endpoint"
       xmlns:s="http://service.jaxws.cxf.apache.org/service"/>

    <jaxws:endpoint id="ALELRService"
        implementor="org.fosstrak.ale.wsdl.alelr.epcglobal.ALELRServicePortTypeImpl"
        endpointName="e:ALELRServicePortType"
        serviceName="s:ALELRService"
        address="/ALELRService"
        xmlns:e="http://service.jaxws.cxf.apache.org/endpoint"
        xmlns:s="http://service.jaxws.cxf.apache.org/service"/>

    <jaxws:endpoint id="ALEController"
        implementor="org.fosstrak.ale.server.controller.ALEControllerImpl"
        endpointName="e:ALEControllerServicePortType"
        serviceName="s:ALEControllerService"
        address="/ALEControllerService"
        xmlns:e="http://service.jaxws.cxf.apache.org/endpoint"
        xmlns:s="http://service.jaxws.cxf.apache.org/service"/>

     <jaxws:endpoint id="LLRPController"
        implementor="org.fosstrak.ale.server.llrp.LLRPControllerImpl"
        endpointName="e:LLRPControllerServicePortType"
        serviceName="s:LLRPControllerService"
        address="/LLRPControllerService"
        xmlns:e="http://service.jaxws.cxf.apache.org/endpoint"
        xmlns:s="http://service.jaxws.cxf.apache.org/service"/>
 </beans>
```

This is the project's pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">


  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <!-- Basics                                                      -->
  <!-- =========================================================== -->

  <groupId>org.fosstrak.fc</groupId>
  <artifactId>fc-server</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>fc</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.fosstrak.fc</groupId>
    <version>1.2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <name>fc-server</name>
  <description>Filtering and Collection Middleware implementing the EPCglobal ALE spec</description>

  <developers>
     <developer>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Benoit Plomion</name>
     </developer>
     <developer>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Wafa Soubra</name>
     </developer>
     <developer>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>Samuel Wieland</name>
     </developer>
     <developer>
        <id>4</id>
        <name>Christian Floerkemeier </name>
     </developer>
  </developers>  

  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <!-- Infrastructure                                              -->
  <!-- =========================================================== -->


    <scm>
            <connection>https://fosstrak.googlecode.com/svn/fc/trunk/fc-server</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://fosstrak.googlecode.com/svn/fc/trunk/fc-server</developerConnection>
            <url>https://fosstrak.googlecode.com/svn/fc/trunk/fc-server</url>
    </scm>



  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <!-- Dependencies                                                -->
  <!-- =========================================================== -->

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.fosstrak.fc</groupId>
      <artifactId>fc-commons</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.fosstrak.reader</groupId>
      <artifactId>reader-rprm-core</artifactId>
      <version>0.5.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
      <groupId>xerces</groupId>
      <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.fosstrak.hal</groupId>
      <artifactId>hal-commons</artifactId>
      <version>0.5.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.fosstrak.hal</groupId>
      <artifactId>hal-impl-sim</artifactId>
      <version>0.5.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.fosstrak.tdt</groupId>
      <artifactId>tdt</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.fosstrak.llrp</groupId>
      <artifactId>llrp-adaptor</artifactId>
      <version>${fosstrak.llrp.version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.fosstrak.reader</groupId>
      <artifactId>reader-rp-proxy</artifactId>
      <version>0.5.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
      <groupId>xerces</groupId>
      <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
      <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>xerces</groupId>
      <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>uk.com.robust-it</groupId>
        <artifactId>cloning</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <!-- Build settings                                              -->
  <!-- =========================================================== -->

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/bin-with-dependencies.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
       <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.6</version>
         <executions>
           <execution>
             <id>unpack</id>
             <phase>compile</phase>
             <goals>
               <goal>unpack</goal>
             </goals>
             <configuration>
               <artifactItems>
                 <artifactItem>
                   <groupId>org.fosstrak.tdt</groupId>
                   <artifactId>tdt</artifactId>
                   <type>jar</type>
                   <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                   <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/tdtschemes</outputDirectory>
                   <includes>**/*.xml,**/*.xsd</includes>
                   <excludes>**/*test.class</excludes>
                 </artifactItem>
               </artifactItems>
             </configuration>
           </execution>
         </executions>
       </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>


</project>
```

There is another project named fc-commons included in the fc-server build path. I can't paste its pom.xml here because of length limitations. You can read it here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=vLv4wPdN

Comment: The stacktrace seems to indicate that the class `ALESettings` has a String property called `vendorVersion` and this property is set to the value `${project.version}`. Spring has identified that as a placeholder to substitute with a value but it fails to substitute because it doesn't know what the value should be. Can you post the relevant Spring config? Also, can you post the pom.xml?

Comment: Thanks. Can you confirm that the file `ale.properties` contains the property `project.version`? Can you also confirm that `ale.properties` is on the project classpath? If you're running in Eclipse, you should ensure that the `src/main/resources` is on the build path by right-clicking the project and going to Properties > Java Build Path > Source tab. Add folder `src/main/resources` if it is not already present.

Comment: Great!! You got it! The project.version property was missing in the ale.properties file. After I added project.version=1.2.2 in ale.properties everything went well. Thank you!!